# pppoe connection keeps disconnecting every 30 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I have hotspot connection. We first connect to wireless and enter a username / password on pppoe connection with windows.

When I use the ubuntu (11.04) I have to use pppoeconf module. Today I setup this module. Then I connect. However, after the 30 seconds wireless will be disconnect. I connect to wireless, then again after the 30 seconds it will be disconnect.

What can I do? There is no problem driver I think because when I don't use the pppoeconf, I try to connect to wireless, then did disconnected. What can I do ?

Every 30 seconds I connect the wireless, it's so boring.

Comment: Post the contents of `/var/log/syslog` containing a full cycle of pppoe to deconnection.

Comment: Share your pppd config please , and you're not using the Network Manager right ?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the logfiles for further information:

```
find /var/log -mmin -1 -ls
```

should show you, which of them got modified in the last minute. With less and grep you can inspect the files found by find:

```
less /var/log/daemon.log 
grep ipw2200 /var/log/kern.log
```

Note: ipw2200 is just an example for my intel-wland-driver ipw2200, your model will most likely be different. Maybe you find out which you have with:

```
lspci | grep -i wireless
sudo lshw -C net | less
```